# I need to switch from database logging to syslog

Tags: 6, database

I'm running a drupal 6 website and I was thinking of speeding it up following these steps:

1. Completely stop database logging
2. Enable syslog

How do I configure Drupal to use syslog?
What if I enable just syslog and disable the database log? Do I have to further configure stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article](http://developed.be/2013/02/26/write-drupal-logs-to-rsyslog-instead-of-to-dblog/) explains the whole process into details.

The very bottom line is activating the Syslog module (a core module), and configure it on admin/settings/logging/syslog. It should already work out-of-the-box.

To make sure you can find the log file, you can set it in /etc/syslog.conf and /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf.